# Define input impedance of a buck converter for ideal converter (efficiency 100%) & practical converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, input-impedance, small-signal, closed-loop

What I know was -The input impedance by the closed-loop buck converter in CCM mode, Zi and, in turn, that presented impedance is dependent on Zo and the duty cycle used by the buck converter
below is the formula after derivation

`Zi=η(Z0/D^2)`

Second Question: What would also be the about small-signal output impedance for Closed-loop buck converter (ideal converter)

Comment: The closed-loop output impedance of a converter is its open-loop output impedance divided by 1+T(s) where T represents the open-loop gain of the converter. Now that impedance depends on the control technique, voltage- or current-mode control for instance. Have a look at my [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) seminar on EMI filter interactions, there are plenty of information on the subject.